# Boosting Fear saves

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Are their any feats that boost Fear saves?

Maybe something similar to Iron Will but specifically against Fear?

Comment: Does it have to be a feat? Could it be a spell, power or a magic item? Could you specify what class and race do you mean to use?

Comment: Yes I meant feat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## There are many

This answer assumes the creature does *not* want to take a feat that simply renders the creature *immune* to fear—like the regional feat **Fearless** (*Player's Guide to Faerun* 38) or the more prerequisite-intensive vile feat **Abyss-bound Soul** (Graz'zt (*Fiendish Codex* I 83)) (*Elder Evils* 11)—, perhaps because the creature wants to realize the benefits of the feat Craven (*Champions of Ruin* 17).

As the question asks for feats similar to the feat [Iron Will](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#iron-will), none of these feats have daunting prerequisites, although their types may limit their availability. With that in mind, the feats below are listed in *likely* order of availability; as always, ask the DM. Urge the DM to be generous: The character may need special dispensation to take a feat that grants bonuses against fear, but it's not like the character's asking for special dispensation to take a feat that grants shadow pounce or *simulacrum* 1/day or something. (And, no, I don't know of any feats that do either of those things.)

- The birth feat **Born under a Rising Sun** (*Dragon* #340 48) grants, among other minor bonuses, a +2 bonus on saving throws against fear. This feat's only requirement is that this feat is the creature's only birth feat. The followup general feat **Spirit of Dawn** (*Dragon* #340 48), in addition to other benefits, increases to +4 the bonus on saving throws against fear.
- The Greyhawk regional feat **World Weary** (*Dragon* #319 61) is probably the best of the bunch, granting a +4 competence bonus on saving throws against fear *and* reducing the effects of fear by 1 step (see *Dungeon Master's Guide* 294 or *Rules Compendium* 53 for an alternative). [Unlike Forgotten Realms regional feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86588/8610), Greyhawk regional feats lack the 1-per-character, exclusively-1st-level restrictions of Forgotten Realms regional feats. Just 2 ranks in the skill Knowledge (local whatever—let's face it: the region'll probably reskinned for the campaign anyway), and the feat's type requirement is met.
- Also a a Greyhawk regional feat, the feat **Raider's Spirit** (*Dragon* #315 54) grants the creature a +4 bonus on saving throws against fear and a +2 bonus on Intimidate skill checks.
- The Lion ancestor feat **Fearsome and Fearless** (*Oriental Adventures* 62) grants the creature a +4 bonus on saving throws against fear and increases by +2 the DCs of fear effects the creature creates. It has no prerequisites, but its type limits it to humans, and it can only be taken at level 1.

Also of interest may be feats with beefier prerequisites like **Indomitable Soul** (*Player's Handbook II* 80), **Trophy Collector** (*PH2* 83-4), or **Unnatural Will** (*Heroes of Horror* 124) and with stricter type requirements like **Steadfast Loyalty** (from [*Savage Tide Player's Guide*](http://paizo.com/dungeonissues/SavageTide/SavageTide_LR.pdf) 4 and which requires the character to be from the Champion's district of [Sasserine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasserine)). However, unfortunately, it appears no general feat from an official source that has no prerequisites has as its benefit that the creature taking it gains, like, a +3 or so bonus on saving throws against fear.

Answer (score 2):

**Unnatural Will** (*Heroes of Horror*)

> Add your Charisma modifier to all Will saves against fear effects. This bonus stacks with any Wisdom bonus you might have to Will saves.

**Cumbrous will** (*Savage Species*)

> Before rolling a Will save, you can decide to activate this feat, which gives you a +6 bonus on your saving throw. After the saving throw is resolved, regardless of the result, you are shaken until the end of the encounter. A shaken character takes a +2 morale penalty on attack rolls, checks, and saving throws.

If you have poor wisdom score in comparision to other abilities, you might be interested in **Steadfast Determination** (*Player's Handbook II*) or **Keen Intellect** (*Oriental Adventures*) to use Consitution or Intelligence modifier instead of Wisdom.