# Can I attack with my move action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, mythic-adventures, move-action

I'm playing *Pathfinder* with a Dex-based warrior. My basic strategy is to use [power attack mythic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-feats/power-attack-mythic/) in my attacks to deal lots of damage per hit and try to attack as much as I can.

In certain situations, my friend uses [mythic haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/#TOC-Mythic-Haste) on me, which gives me a bonus move action. Since I have the most HP in the group (tanker by lack of options) my basic strategy is to stay close to the enemies, which usually makes the additional movement action a waste.

To be precise I'm a hybrid fighter-slayer; until now I've been using [Fleet Charge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/champion/#TOC-Fleet-Charge-Ex) to attack (and approach if needed), [Amazing Initiative](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/#Amazing_Initiative_Ex) to another attack and a full attack (BAB +10(haste)/+10/+5). Sometimes it can be a waste to have another move action. Gladly, with Keen Edge active, sometimes I don't need to use all the attacks.

Is there a way to use my move action to attack?

Comment: You may be *vaguely* interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91121/8610)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this post is ancient, but, for completeness sake there *is* one way to attack as a move action, if you're a magus/arcanist/warpriest: [The Signifier's Fist](https://aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Signifer%27s%20Fist) . This light mace allows you to spend an arcane pool / arcane reservoir / use of fervor to make an attack with it as a move action. It also *does* some stuff on that attack, since it's supposed to be a special attack, but if you want to attack as a move action, it's the only way.

Answer (score 4):

### No, you cannot use your Move action to attack.

There is no ability, even in Mythic rules, to perform an attack action by spending a move action.

There is generally a hierarchy of power in actions

- Full Actions should be the "most powerful" and consume a Standard and Move action (usually your only Standard and Move, unless you are granted bonus actions); note that this does not mean that a Standard and a Move "equal" a Full Action, only that using a Full Action means you have neither your Standard nor Move action afterward
- Standard actions tend to be abilities that alter the play field such as by damaging enemies, but are less than Full Actions. Alternatively, you can *choose* to do anything a Move action can do as a Standard action
- Swift/Immediate actions are an assortment of abilities that can be similar to a Standard or Move action, but don't take up that action; a Mythic ability might allow you to expend a Swift action to make an attack, or [Swashbucklers](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler) get [numerous ways to use Swift actions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Swashbuckler/#TOC-Deeds), from standing up to counter-attacking. You *cannot* choose to do Swift actions as other action types unless you have a specific ability to do so.
- Move actions tend to assist you in some way, rather than hamper enemies (such as putting you into position to attack something or standing back up)
- Free actions tend to be a grab-bag of not changing much

There are a *plethora* of abilities that alter the action cost of... actions. For instance, Quick Draw turns your Move action/"part of a Move action" weapon draw into a Free action. However, I have not been able to find *any* ability that allows you to "upgrade" your Move action(s) into Standard actions, nor perform an attack as a Move action.